# Unable to find machine level gitconfig file on Mac

Tags: git, macos

I am using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4, which comes with git installed. I was trying to find my machine level `gitconfig` file.

Typed:
`$ git config --system --list`

Got:
`fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory`

Why is this happening? How can I find it?

The user level git file exists at `~/.gitconfig` though.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you do not have the file `/etc/gitconfig`.

The error will go away if you simply create the file. Since it is a system directory, you will need `sudo`.

```
sudo touch /etc/gitconfig
```

Without that file, this error reproduces even on my Ubuntu system, so it's not an OSX-specific issue.

```
git config --system --list
fatal: unable to read config file '/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
sudo touch /etc/gitconfig
git config --system --list
# No output
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, if I create the file, the error would go away. but I thought there would be a machine level git config file since git is already installed. 

`$ git config --global --list` just worked without me creating the `~/.config/git/config` file.

Comment: @JunYin, Based on our two samples, it looks like the git installation does not come with such a file. Whether that's because of oversight or lack of use, I suspect only the maintainers know.